# Network debugging

Tags: monitoring

I have a set of 30 Linux machines each connected to a Cisco 1 GB switch. I am seeing the following issues:

1. Ping time between machines are different.
2. File transfer rate is different between these machines.
3. Number of UDP packets received by these machines are different.

I have:

1. Checked switch and each port is functioning at 1 GB.
2. Made sure that the correct Ethernet modules are installed and compiled again.
3. Most (25) machines are identical in hardware/make and model.
4. Changes switch not much of the difference.

What are the steps/ideas to get to the bottom of this issue?

The problem is installing some monitoring software on all machines may not be possible but at most another machine can be added and that can be used to monitor the network, but what kind of things to start looking at?

Comment: You need to add some more information. How much difference is there in the ICMP replies? ICMP is not a good tool to measure with to start with. How much difference is there in the transfer rates? How are you measuring the transfer rates? Why are you looking at UDP packets?

Comment: And what is the model number of the Cisco switch in question? And what variance in the work loads exists on the machines?  And on a given (single) machine, do the ping/file-transfer-rates vary or are constant?

Comment: ping time for 25 packets differs by .010 to 0.25. Also I am checking using pv and netcat. For example I run nc -ulp 1234 > /dev/null on 1 machine and on another pv < /dev/zero | nc -u1234. This also varies from machine to machine.  The acute problem I have is few windwos machine. I am simply copying file from windows 2008 server (default install) to a Linux machine using winscp - this shows me around 16 mb as transfer rate, but when I copy (scp) same file from Linux to another linux its around 68 to 69 mb per second.

Comment: The basic testing of file transfer, ping, pv + netcat etc carried out when there is nothing (other than standard linux services are running). Each machine is installed using same Ubuntu CD.  The hardware varies only in terms of CPU for example on one machine its Xeon 2.0 GHz while on other machine its 2.40 GHz Xeon. ethtool, mii-tools, nm-tool all most all say everything is fine.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here? None of what you mention above may be indicative of an actual problem with the network.

Comment: You said you changed the switch and it made no difference. What makes you think the network is to blame then ?

Comment: Agreed. The problem you're encountering is unclear. I'm guessing that you're seeing (occasional? frequent? repeatable?) slowness for WinSCP transfers from a Win2k8 server to various Ubuntu servers. Variance in ping times of the magnitude you listed is not indicative of an issue (as others have pointed out ICMP is not the greatest measurement tool). Further, if you're losing UDP packets, I would think there's got to be packet drops on at least one of your switch interfaces. Switch model & IOS version would help, too.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because ping times are distinct, the problem should be between layer 1 and layer3.

the first step is to see if it is a layer1 issue. I would check the errors on the switch interfaces. If errors are appearing on the interfaces, I will try to change the cables or the interfaces on the switch to see if the problem is persistent for the same Linux devices.
If still persists, Linux servers should have the problem.

Comment: I checked switch, there are no errors or packet drops. Does length of cable make difference?

Comment: As long as it's under 100m, you shouldn't have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you issue a show controllers ethernet-controller gigabitEthernet 0/1 ?  If so, what did you notice on each interface that your are having trouble with?  I agree with irina, check L1 first, then further check your switch for controller errors if there are any.  If you can rule that out, the most likely culprit is the machine or configuration of the machine.